# $0<y(t)<\frac{1}{t+1}+\int_0^t\frac{y^2(s)}{t+1}ds , y(0)<1 \space \forall t\geq 0$ Prove $y(t)<1 \space \forall t\geq 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$0<y(t)<\frac{1}{t+1}+\int_0^t\frac{y^2(s)}{t+1}ds , y(0)<1 \space \forall t\geq 0$

Prove $y(t)<1 \space \forall t\geq 0$

$\int_0^t\frac{y^2(s)}{t+1}ds=\frac{1}{t+1}\cdot\frac{y^3(t)-y^3(0)}{3}$

$0<y(t)<\frac{1}{t+1}+\frac{1}{t+1}\cdot\frac{y^3(t)-y^3(0)}{3}=\frac{3+y^3(t)-y^3(0)}{3(t+1)}$

I got stuck, help is welcome.

Thanks !

Comment: Just to be sure: Is it $\int_0^t\frac{y^2(s)}{t+1}ds$ or $\int_0^t\frac{y^2(s)}{s+1}ds$ in the integral inequality? – Note that $\int_0^t\frac{y^2(s)}{t+1}ds=\frac{1}{t+1}\cdot\frac{y^3(t)-y^3(0)}{3}$ is wrong.

Comment: Why is it wrong ? The correct one is $\int_0^t\frac{y^2(s)}{t+1}ds$ Then $\int_0^t\frac{y^2(s)}{t+1}ds=\frac{1}{t+1}\int_0^ty^2(s)ds$

Comment: Yes, but $\int_0^ty^2(s)ds \ne \cdot\frac{y^3(t)-y^3(0)}{3}$.

Comment: Ohh, thanks ! Any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $g(t) = \int_0^t y^2(s)\, ds$. Then $g(0) = 0$ and
$$
 g'(t) = y^2(t) < \left( \frac{1+g(t)}{1+t}\right)^2
$$
or
$$
\frac{g'(t)}{(1+g(t))^2} < \frac{1}{(1+t)^2} \, .
$$
Integrating this inequality gives
$$
 1- \frac{1}{1+g(t)} \le 1  - \frac{1}{1+t}
$$
and that is equivalent to $g(t) \le t$. Then
$$ 
y(t) < \frac{1+g(t)}{1+t} \le 1 \, .
$$